# Powershell with regex: Unable to find and replace ALL occurences of specified string in a set of data

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I am new to regular expressions and stackoverflow.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to remove unwanted data from a data set.  The data is contained in a .csv file column with multiple cells, each cell containing data similar to this:

OSVDB #109124,OSVDB #109125,OSVDB #109126,OSVDB #109127,OSVDB #109128,OSVDB #109129,OSVDB #109130,OSVDB #109131,OSVDB #109132,OSVDB #109133,OSVDB #109134,OSVDB #109135,OSVDB #109136,OSVDB #109137,OSVDB #109138,OSVDB #109139,OSVDB #109140,OSVDB #109141,OSVDB #109142,OSVDB #109143,VMSA #2014-0012,OSVDB #102715,OSVDB #104972,OSVDB #106710,OSVDB #115364,IAVA #2014-A-0191,IAVB #2014-B-0160,IAVB #2014-B-0162,IAVB #2015-B-0007

I want to replace the above data with each occurrence of the strings beginning "IAV...". So, the above cell would read:

```
IAVA #2014-A-0191,IAVB #2014-B-0160,IAVB #2014-B-0162,IAVB #2015-B-0007
```

Below is a snippet of the script that imports the .csv and gets the column containing the data.
    My regex, within powershell is:

```
$reg1 = '$1'
$reg2 = '(IAV[A|B]\s#[0-9]{4}-[A|B]-[0-9]{4}){1,}'

ForEach-Object {$_.IAVM = [regex]::replace($_.IAVM,$reg2,$reg1); $_}
```

The result is:

The entire cell contents posted above.

From my understanding `{1,}` at the end of the regex should return each occurrence of the string pattern, but I'm returning all contents of every cell containing my regex string.

Comment: You may want to use some of the code comments available to make your post slightly more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of trying to pick out your string you just delete the stuff you don't want?  Try something like:

```
$reg1=''
$reg2='((OSVDB|VMSA)\s#[M-S0-9-]{6,9}[,]?)'
```

Comment: This method worked for me.  Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You have `.*` in that regex at the very beginning. This will capture *everything* up to the last match of the pat that follows it. In your case I don't think you need that part anyway.

Also note that PowerShell has a handy `-replace` operator, so there's often no reason to use the static methods on the Regex type.